# Is it possible to filter HTTP Headers in Shodan?

Tags: http-headers, shodan

The [Shodan filter reference](https://www.shodan.io/search/filters) only shows a way to search using the hash of all the HTTP headers (`http.headers_hash`) in a banner. Is there some way to search for specific header fields or values?

Comment: hello, as per Oct 9 2023 my answer applies. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just search for them directly as they're contained in the main `data` property of the banner. You don't need to use search filters. For example: https://www.shodan.io/search?query=%22X-Recruiting%3A%22

Comment: This should not be accepted as the answer. You can use the query http.headers_hash

Comment: The `http.headers_hash` lets you search for banners that have specific headers in a specific order. I.e. it's good for fingerprinting. The original question as I understood it was for finding services that contain a specific header. I.e. it's not about the fingerprint of the headers but rather a specific header key/ value.

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer is to use the Shodan HTTP search filter `http.headers_hash` as seen on their official page [here](https://www.shodan.io/search/filters).